# Capistrano not recognizing multistage stage

Tags: deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to get a multistage capistrano deployment to my production and staging servers. Here's my `deploy.rb` file (scm details omitted):

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'whenever/capistrano'

set :application, "myapp"

set :stages, %w{staging, production}
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :deploy_to, "/webapps/myapp"

set(:domain) { "#{domain}" }
role(:web) { domain }
role(:app) { domain }
role(:db, :primary => true) { domain }

default_run_options[:pty] = true

namespace :one do
    task :foo do
        puts "foo"
    end
end
```

And in `config/deploy/production.rb`:

```
set :domain, "production.com"
set :user, "prod"
```

`config/deploy/staging.rb`:

```
set :domain, "shootsystage.com"
set :user, "stage"
```

Nothing too exotic going on (I think). Running `cap production one:foo` works fine. But running `cap staging one:foo` results in:

```
the task `staging' does not exist
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a small piece of syntax bit me in the butt. It should be:

```
set :stages, %w{staging production}
```

Note the lack of commas in the `%w{}`. Ffffuuuuuuuuuuu...

Comment: ouch - got bitten by that one as well - annoying since of course the system tells you it can find the staging, but no sign of the production.